# Binary operator * cannot be applied to operands of type Int and CGFloat

Tags: ios, swift

**i** had type **Int**. please help me fix that?

[image]

Comment: Why float variable and int variable unable to multiple? why not result value failed to typeCast here! You comments help!                                                                                  let price : Float = 10.5  let quantity : Int = 20 var total : Float.                                  total = price * quantity.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Instead of `i * self.view.frame.size.width`, use `CGFloat(i) * self.view.frame.size.width`

Comment: This is the utter nonsense that all other programming languages handle in math statements. Swift is utterly useless for complex math. Its most serious drawback and which makes it nearly impossible to convert legacy code bases which do complex Math and are wherein a competent programmer can depend on certain assumptions.

Answer (score 2):

You need to type cast  **i** into CGFloat, write your line of code as

`var frame: CGRect = CGRectMake(CGFloat(i) * self.view.fram.size.width, self.tutorialHolderView.frame.origin.y, 0, self.tutorialHolderView.frame.size.height)`